# Recovering a borked /boot partition

Tags: raspbian, apt, boot-issues

After a apt-get update/apt-get upgrade ended with errors, my system became unusable.  I was able to determine that the /boot partition was missing several files (useful ones, like kernel.img...)

I copied the missing files from another pi's /boot partition, but I don't know if the versions are in sync with this one.    The pi does boot, and seems to work correctly, although a couple of my startup customizations seems to have been lost.

Is there a list of packages that I should reinstall to sync the files in /boot?

The only files that were on /boot after it was corrupted were:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  0 tom    staff     152 Jan 19  2014 cmdline.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  0 tom    staff    1179 Aug 25  2013 config.txt  
-rwxrwxrwx  0 tom    staff     137 Feb  9  2013 issue.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  0 tom    staff 3572200 Oct 28 03:09 start_x.elf
```

(this list is from a tarball I made on my mac before I copied files from the other system, thus the unusual owner/group)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to download a recent system image, extract the image onto the harddrive, and copy the content of the `/boot` partition to that of the RaspberryPi's SD Card. Additionally, you have to copy the kernel modules, i.e. the content of `/usr/lib/modules/<kernel_release>` from the extracted system image to the SD Card.

You may also want to keep `/boot/config.txt`, which contains the boot configuration.

Comment: cmdline.txt is also custom in my case -- this box actually boots from an NFS filesystem.

Comment: Will apt-get be in sync after doing this?